# MahApps use datePicker with time

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to use MahApps datepicker in my application .I was looking into the code and was not able to find how to assign custom mins difference like 0, 5, 10, 15 during time selection in datepicker can somebody guide me how can I do it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 different lists which you can use for the properties `SourceHours`, `SourceMinutes` and `SourceSeconds` like

```
<Controls:DateTimePicker SourceMinutes="{x:Static Controls:TimePickerBase.IntervalOf5}" />
```

or `IntervalOf10` and `IntervalOf15`. They all type of `IEnumerable<int>`.

(Controls is `xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"`)